# Finding max value from an array ([[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]])

Tags: python-3.x, oop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find max value of the above mention array. mad min value. The data is of vehicles present on the road. I am trying to find max accelration and deceleration at a time

Comment: Is this actually a list of lists, or is it an array from python's builtin [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), or is it a [numpy array](https://numpy.org/)? In any case, this question has been [asked and answered before](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953), on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. If you tried something already and are having trouble with it, please provide a [mre] and ask a _specific_ question. Also read [tour], [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming [x, y] is x and y axis acceleration. And by acceleration value, You mean sqrt(x^2 + y^2) value. Then, You can:

```
import numpy as np

accelerating_cars = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]

index_min = np.argmin(list(map(lambda x: x[0]**2 + x[1]**2, accelerating_cars)))
```

For max in same way